# Functionality in Update Panels not working in IE9 or IE10

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

We have an issue where functionality within Microsoft ajax "UpdatePanel" does not work or takes an extremely long time to react in IE 9 and/or IE 10.

If we set the compatibility to IE 8 the functionality works properly.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
```

The functionality works fine in other browser (Chrome/Firefox).
Also, this behavior happens in some environments but not others running the same code base.

Setting the compatibility mode solves the functionality problem but limits CSS ability for all IE users.